# Routing all web 'traffic' via tun device on Mac OSX

Tags: macos

Having checked through Stack Overflow I cannot find a suitable answer, so hope the community are able to help me.

I am using a DNS tunneling program called iodine, on the Mac as a client device and am currently able to connect to the server correctly, create the `tun0` device and ping the server as defined, via the tunnel.

I am now trying to route my normal browsing traffic via this 'virtual' `tun0` device but am failing to do so. I have seen some reference to amending the preferences.plist but cannot seem to get it to connect properly (presume due to my inability to find or define the UUID)

Anyway, if anyone has any ideas they will all be greatly received.

```
ifconfig tun0: flags=8851<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1130
inet 10.0.0.2 --> 10.0.0.2 netmask 0xffffffe0 
open (pid 447)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, rerouting traffic through a tunnel is done by changing the default route in the routing table on your system using a command such as `route add default 10.0.0.2`.  It may also be necessary to remove the existing default route to avoid confusing the routing subsystem.

Comment: Having tried to add the route, I am informed that it already exists (which I think it what you refer to as a possible need to remove the existing). How would one go about removing the existing current default and once tunneling is completed, how would you refer back?

Comment: To delete a route, you use the `route delete` option.  To delete a default route, try: `route delete default`.  Also note that you must have root or sudo access to change the routing tables.

Comment: Superb that worked a treat.